# Second week of C++, input arguments need to return an error if they contain an alpha character

Tags: c++, parsing

Using if control statement write a program to output error message if IDE program input arguments contain an alpha character.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  cout<<argv[1]<<endl;
  cout<<argv[2]<<endl;    

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Show us your code, please. We're not here to do homework for you, but if you have a specific question and you show us you're trying we can help you out.

Comment: Most computers today uses the [ASCII alphabet](http://www.asciitable.com/). If you look at that table, I'm sure you can figure something out. And remember that character literals and their ASCII value are interchangeable. So e.g. the character literal `'a'` equals `97`. I recommend using the character literals in your comparison for readability.

Comment: edit your question, do not put information in the comments

Comment: Sorry everyone its my second week at this

Comment: Okay, so far you are printing out the arguments. What you need to to is check each argument to see if it contains an alphabetic character. What have you actually tried here? As it stands, your code doesn't make any attempt on this

Comment: As a hint, you might want to try isaplha, which checks a `char` to see if it is an alphabetic character.

Comment: I left an answer—hopefully it helps. If not, please edit your question to clarify what you're struggling with so everyone can pitch in, and leave a comment so I can edit my own answer to be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell where you're stuck, but I'll do my best to help. I apologize if I waste time on things you already know.

Let's say you pass this to your program (through the IDE or command line): `1156 q.p`

`argc` then is 3 (the first argument is the name of the program itself), and `argv` looks like this:

```
argv[0] = "program_name";
argv[1] = "1156";
argv[2] = "q.p";
```

Things to keep in mind: the number of arguments isn't fixed, and if you try to read more arguments than you were passed your program will crash. (Technically, it causes undefined behavior, which means anything could happen.)

C strings are just arrays of characters with a special NULL character at the end, like this:

```
char program_name[] = {'p', 'r', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'm', 0};
```

Characters can be treated like numbers—actually, they are numbers. These lines both do the same thing:

```
char a = 'a';
char a = 97;
```

That also means you can compare them: `'a' == 97`, and `'a' < 'z'`.

ASCII characters are mapped conveniently: 0-9, A-Z, and a-z map to 48-57, 65-90, and 97-122, respectively. This means, for example, a character is a digit if it's between '0' and '9', inclusive.

To test every character in a string, you'll need to loop over it. This example checks to see if every character in a string is 'X':

```
bool is_all_Xs(const char *str) {
    for(int i = 0; str[i] != 0; ++i) {
        if(str[i] != 'X') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hopefully this is enough to point you in the right direction.